# Problem with m.Connection() ("v1 not found in results file")

Tags: python, gekko

I am trying to use `m.Connection()` in order to simplify (reduce the number of variables in the model) a complex model. However, it gives the error `v1 not found in results file`. It is able to solve the simulation, but the problem comes up when loading the results.

You can replicate the error with this code:

```
from gekko import GEKKO
import numpy as np

m = GEKKO(remote=False)
m.time = np.linspace(0,20,100)

u = m.MV()
x = m.SV()
y = m.SV()
z = m.SV()

m.Equations([
    x.dt() == x + u,
    y == 2*z - 0.1*u
])
m.Connection(z, x)

m.options.IMODE = 4
m.solve()
```

Here's my error message:

```
KeyError                                  Traceback (most recent call last)
Cell In [9], line 18
     15 m.Connection(z, x)
     17 m.options.IMODE = 4
---> 18 m.solve()

File D:\python\hestia\models\.venv\lib\site-packages\gekko\gekko.py:2227, in GEKKO.solve(self, disp, debug, GUI, **kwargs)
   2225 if timing == True:
   2226     t = time.time()
-> 2227 self.load_JSON()
   2228 if timing == True:
   2229     print('load JSON', time.time() - t)

File D:\python\hestia\models\.venv\lib\site-packages\gekko\gk_post_solve.py:70, in load_JSON(self)
     68                         vp.__dict__[o] = pred
     69             else: #everything besides value and pred
---> 70                 vp.__dict__[o] = data[vp.name][o]
     71 return data

KeyError: 'v1'
```

Anybody with this problem? any workaround?

Answer (score 0):

Try using simple equalities such as `m.Equation(z==x)` with `m.options.REDUCE=1` or more. The `REDUCE` function iteratively looks for variables that can be eliminated from the problem. A scan of `3` runs through the model 3 times before giving it to the solver.

```py
from gekko import GEKKO

m = GEKKO(remote=False)
m.time = [0,1,2,3]

u = m.MV()
x = m.SV()
y = m.SV()
z = m.SV()

m.Equations([
    x.dt() == x + u,
    y == 2*z - 0.1*u
])
m.Equation(z==x)

m.options.IMODE=4
m.options.REDUCE=3
m.solve()
```

One other small modification is to use `m.options.IMODE=4` to change to dynamic simulation mode.

```
 ----------------------------------------------------------------
 APMonitor, Version 1.0.0
 APMonitor Optimization Suite
 ----------------------------------------------------------------
 
 
 --------- APM Model Size ------------
 Each time step contains
   Objects      :  0
   Constants    :  0
   Variables    :  4
   Intermediates:  0
   Connections  :  0
   Equations    :  3
   Residuals    :  3
 
 Number of state variables:    12
 Number of total equations: -  12
 Number of slack variables: -  0
 ---------------------------------------
 Degrees of freedom       :    0
 
 **********************************************
 Dynamic Simulation with Interior Point Solver
 **********************************************
  
  
 Info: Exact Hessian

******************************************************************************
This program contains Ipopt, a library for large-scale nonlinear optimization.
 Ipopt is released as open source code under the Eclipse Public License (EPL).
         For more information visit http://projects.coin-or.org/Ipopt
******************************************************************************

This is Ipopt version 3.10.2, running with linear solver mumps.

Number of nonzeros in equality constraint Jacobian...:       26
Number of nonzeros in inequality constraint Jacobian.:        0
Number of nonzeros in Lagrangian Hessian.............:        0

Total number of variables............................:       12
                     variables with only lower bounds:        0
                variables with lower and upper bounds:        0
                     variables with only upper bounds:        0
Total number of equality constraints.................:       12
Total number of inequality constraints...............:        0
        inequality constraints with only lower bounds:        0
   inequality constraints with lower and upper bounds:        0
        inequality constraints with only upper bounds:        0

iter    objective    inf_pr   inf_du lg(mu)  ||d||  lg(rg) alpha_du alpha_pr  ls
   0 0.0000000e+000 0.00e+000 0.00e+000   0.0 0.00e+000    -  0.00e+000 0.00e+000   0
Cannot recompute multipliers for feasibility problem.  Error in eq_mult_calculator

Number of Iterations....: 0

                                   (scaled)                 (unscaled)
Objective...............:  0.0000000000000000e+000   0.0000000000000000e+000
Dual infeasibility......:  0.0000000000000000e+000   0.0000000000000000e+000
Constraint violation....:  0.0000000000000000e+000   0.0000000000000000e+000
Complementarity.........:  0.0000000000000000e+000   0.0000000000000000e+000
Overall NLP error.......:  0.0000000000000000e+000   0.0000000000000000e+000


Number of objective function evaluations             = 1
Number of objective gradient evaluations             = 1
Number of equality constraint evaluations            = 1
Number of inequality constraint evaluations          = 0
Number of equality constraint Jacobian evaluations   = 1
Number of inequality constraint Jacobian evaluations = 0
Number of Lagrangian Hessian evaluations             = 0
Total CPU secs in IPOPT (w/o function evaluations)   =      0.001
Total CPU secs in NLP function evaluations           =     -0.000

EXIT: Optimal Solution Found.

 The solution was found.

 The final value of the objective function is  0.
 
 ---------------------------------------------------
 Solver         :  IPOPT (v3.12)
 Solution time  :  0.002999999999999999 sec
 Objective      :  0.
 Successful solution
 ---------------------------------------------------
```

Comment: Many thanks for your reply @John. I just corrected the IMODE error. Would it be better to use `m.Connection()` instead the equality? or is it intended for different usage?

Comment: The `m.Connection()` is typically for connecting pre-built objects such as those listed here: https://apmonitor.com/wiki/index.php/Main/Objects  The simple inequalities with `m.options.REDUCE=3` should be fast and accomplish the same thing.